# This is a sorting algorithm visualization program

Tags: java, object-oriented, sorting, swing, data-visualization

Configs.java

```java
package main;

/**
 * @author Daniel
 * 
 * A load of configs for the application.
 */

public class Configs {
    public static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Sorting Algorithm Animation";

    public static final int APPLICATION_WIDTH = 1280;
    public static final int APPLICATION_HEIGHT = 720;

    public static final int DISPLAY_PANEL_WIDTH = Configs.APPLICATION_WIDTH * 4 / 5;
    public static final int DISPLAY_PANEL_HEIGHT = Configs.APPLICATION_HEIGHT;

    public static final int BUTTONS_PANEL_WIDTH = Configs.APPLICATION_WIDTH / 5;
    public static final int BUTTONS_PANEL_HEIGHT = Configs.APPLICATION_HEIGHT;

    public static final int INITIAL_LIST_STARTING_VALUE = 1024;

    public static final String[] ALL_SORTS_COMBO_BOX_VALUES = {"Bubble Sort", "Quick Sort", "Selection Sort", "Insertion Sort", "Merge Sort"};

    public static final int MAXIMUM_DELAY_VALUE = 10000;
    public static final int MINIMUM_DELAY_VALUE = 0;
    public static final int TICK_SPACING = 3333;



    public static final int INITIAL_DELAY_VALUE = MAXIMUM_DELAY_VALUE / 2;
}
```

SortingAlgorithmAnimationApp.java

```java
package main;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import gui.AppGUI;

/**
 * @author Daniel
 * 
 * The driver class.
 */

public class SortingAlgorithmAnimationApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(AppGUI::new);
    }
}
```

AppGUI,java

```java
package gui;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import gui_components.GUIComponents;
import main.Configs;
import storage.NumbersList;

/**
 * @author Daniel
 * 
 * Puts the GUI  together.
 */

public class AppGUI {
    public AppGUI() {
        NumbersList.generateList(Configs.INITIAL_LIST_STARTING_VALUE);

        initGUI();
    }

    private void initGUI() {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();

        window.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        window.getContentPane().add(GUIComponents.buttonsPanel);
        window.getContentPane().add(GUIComponents.displayPanel);

        window.setTitle(Configs.APPLICATION_NAME);
        window.setResizable(false);

        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.pack();

        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

GUIComponents.java

```java
package gui_components;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;

import drawing.PaintSurface;
import main.Configs;
import sorting_algorithms.BubbleSort;
import sorting_algorithms.InsertionSort;
import sorting_algorithms.MergeSort;
import sorting_algorithms.QuickSort;
import sorting_algorithms.SelectionSort;
import sorting_algorithms.SortingAlgorithm;
import storage.NumbersList;

/**
 * @author Daniel
 * 
 * Creates and holds all the GUI components.
 */

public class GUIComponents {
    // don't let anyone instantiate this class.
    private GUIComponents() {}

    public static JPanel buttonsPanel, displayPanel;

    private static JButton newListButton;
    public static JSlider delaySlider;
    private static JButton randomizeListButton;
    private static JComboBox<String> allSortsComboBox;
    private static JButton doSortButton;

    private static SortingAlgorithm algorithm;

    static {
        initButtonsPanel();
        displayPanel = new PaintSurface();
    }

    private static void initButtonsPanel() {
        buttonsPanel = new JPanel();

        buttonsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Configs.BUTTONS_PANEL_WIDTH, Configs.BUTTONS_PANEL_HEIGHT));
        buttonsPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);


        initNewListButton();
        initDelaySlider();
        initRandomizeListButton();
        initAllSortsComboBox();
        initDoSortButton();


        buttonsPanel.add(new JLabel("Sorting Delay (ms)"));
        buttonsPanel.add(delaySlider);

        buttonsPanel.add(newListButton);

        buttonsPanel.add(randomizeListButton);

        buttonsPanel.add(allSortsComboBox);
        buttonsPanel.add(doSortButton);
    }

    private static void initNewListButton() {
        newListButton = new JButton("New List");

        newListButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent event) -> {
            int amount = NumbersList.getList().length;

            try {
                String temp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many numbers?", "Enter Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                if(temp != null && temp.length() > 0) {
                    amount = Integer.parseInt(temp);
                } else return;
            } catch(java.lang.NumberFormatException exception) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something went wrong!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }

            if(amount < 0 || amount > 1024) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Amount! 0 - 1024 only.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }

            NumbersList.generateList(amount);
            GUIComponents.displayPanel.repaint();
        });
    }

    private static void initDelaySlider() {
        delaySlider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, Configs.MINIMUM_DELAY_VALUE, Configs.MAXIMUM_DELAY_VALUE, Configs.INITIAL_DELAY_VALUE);
        delaySlider.setMajorTickSpacing(Configs.TICK_SPACING);
        delaySlider.setMinorTickSpacing(10);
        delaySlider.setPaintLabels(true);
        delaySlider.setSnapToTicks(true);
        delaySlider.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        delaySlider.addChangeListener((ChangeEvent event) -> {
            if(algorithm != null)
                algorithm.changeDelay(delaySlider.getValue() * 1000);
        });
    }

    private static void initRandomizeListButton() {
        randomizeListButton = new JButton("Randomize List");
        randomizeListButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent event) -> {
            NumbersList.randomizeList();
            GUIComponents.displayPanel.repaint();
        });
    }

    private static void initAllSortsComboBox() {
        allSortsComboBox = new JComboBox<String>(Configs.ALL_SORTS_COMBO_BOX_VALUES);
    }

    private static void initDoSortButton() {
        doSortButton = new JButton("Do Sort");

        doSortButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent event) -> {
            randomizeListButton.setEnabled(false);
            newListButton.setEnabled(false);
            doSortButton.setEnabled(false);
            allSortsComboBox.setEnabled(false);

            switch((String) allSortsComboBox.getSelectedItem()) {

            case "Bubble Sort":
                algorithm = new BubbleSort();
                break;

            case "Quick Sort":
                algorithm = new QuickSort();
                break;

            case "Selection Sort":
                algorithm = new SelectionSort();
                break;

            case "Insertion Sort":
                algorithm = new InsertionSort();
                break;

            case "Merge Sort":
                algorithm = new MergeSort();
                break;
            }

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    algorithm.doSort(NumbersList.getList());

                    randomizeListButton.setEnabled(true);
                    newListButton.setEnabled(true);
                    doSortButton.setEnabled(true);
                    allSortsComboBox.setEnabled(true);
                }}).start();



            displayPanel.repaint();
        });
    }
}
```

NumbersList.java

```java
package storage;

import main.Configs;

/**
 * @author Daniel
 * 
 * Holds the list and methods concerning the list.
 */

public class NumbersList {
    private static int[] numbers;

    public static void generateList(int amount) {
        numbers = new int[amount];

        double spacing = (double) Configs.APPLICATION_HEIGHT / amount, height = spacing;
        for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            numbers[i] = (int) (height);

            height += spacing;
        }
    }

    public static void randomizeList() {
        for(int i = 0; i < NumbersList.numbers.length; i++) {
            int temp = NumbersList.numbers[i];
            int randomPlace = (int) (Math.random() * NumbersList.numbers.length);

            NumbersList.numbers[i] = NumbersList.numbers[randomPlace];
            NumbersList.numbers[randomPlace] = temp;
        }
    }

    public static int[] getList() {
        return NumbersList.numbers;
    }
}
```

PaintSurface.java

```java
package drawing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import main.Configs;
import storage.NumbersList;

/**
 * @author Daniel
 * 
 * The display panel for the animation.
 */

public class PaintSurface extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static int currentBarIndex = 0;

    public PaintSurface() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Configs.DISPLAY_PANEL_WIDTH, Configs.DISPLAY_PANEL_HEIGHT));

        this.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        super.paintComponent(graphics);

        int[] listNumbers = NumbersList.getList();

        double x = 0, width = (double) Configs.DISPLAY_PANEL_WIDTH / listNumbers.length;
        for(int i = 0; i < listNumbers.length; i++) {
            if(currentBarIndex == i)
                graphics.setPaint(Color.RED);
            else
                graphics.setPaint(Color.BLACK);

            graphics.fillRect((int) x, Configs.APPLICATION_HEIGHT - listNumbers[i], (int) width + 1, listNumbers[i]);

            x += width;
        }

        graphics.dispose();
        g.dispose();
    }
}
```

BubbleSort.java

```java
package sorting_algorithms;

import gui_components.GUIComponents;

/**
 * @author Daniel
 * 
 * Implementation of the bubble sort.
 */

public class BubbleSort implements SortingAlgorithm {
    private int delay = GUIComponents.delaySlider.getValue() * 1000;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Bubble Sort";
    }

    @Override
    public void doSort(int[] nums) {
        int n = nums.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
                if (nums[j] > nums[j + 1]) {
                    int temp = nums[j];
                    nums[j] = nums[j + 1];
                    nums[j + 1] = temp;

                    SortingAlgorithm.setCurrentBar(j+1);
                    SortingAlgorithm.sleepFor(delay);
                }

        SortingAlgorithm.setCurrentBar(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void changeDelay(int delay) {
        this.delay = delay;
    }
}
```

QuickSort.java

```java
package sorting_algorithms;

import gui_components.GUIComponents;

public class QuickSort implements SortingAlgorithm {
    private int delay = GUIComponents.delaySlider.getValue() * 1000;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Quick Sort";
    }

    @Override
    public void doSort(int[] nums) {
        sort(nums, 0, nums.length - 1);
    }

    private int partition(int nums[], int low, int high) {
        int pivot = nums[high];
        int i = (low - 1);
        for (int j = low; j < high; j++) {
            if (nums[j] < pivot) {
                i++;

                int temp = nums[i];
                nums[i] = nums[j];
                nums[j] = temp;

                SortingAlgorithm.setCurrentBar(j);
                SortingAlgorithm.sleepFor(delay);
            }
        }

        int temp = nums[i + 1];
        nums[i + 1] = nums[high];
        nums[high] = temp;

        return i + 1;
    }

    private void sort(int nums[], int low, int high) {
        if (low < high) {
            int pi = partition(nums, low, high);

            sort(nums, low, pi - 1);
            sort(nums, pi + 1, high);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void changeDelay(int delay) {
        this.delay = delay;
    }
}
```

SelectionSort.java

```java
package sorting_algorithms;

import gui_components.GUIComponents;

/**
 * @author Daniel
 * 
 * Implementation of the selection sort.
 */

public class SelectionSort implements SortingAlgorithm {
    private int delay = GUIComponents.delaySlider.getValue() * 1000;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Selection Sort";
    }

    @Override
    public void doSort(int[] nums) {
        int n = nums.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            int minIndex = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
                if (nums[j] < nums[minIndex]) {
                    minIndex = j;

                    SortingAlgorithm.setCurrentBar(i);
                    SortingAlgorithm.setCurrentBar(j);
                    SortingAlgorithm.sleepFor(delay);
                }

            int temp = nums[minIndex];
            nums[minIndex] = nums[i];
            nums[i] = temp;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void changeDelay(int delay) {
        this.delay = delay;
    }
}
```

InsertionSort.java

```java
package sorting_algorithms;

import gui_components.GUIComponents;

/**
 * @author Daniel
 * 
 * Implementation of the insertion sort.
 */

public class InsertionSort implements SortingAlgorithm {
    private int delay = GUIComponents.delaySlider.getValue() * 1000;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Insertion Sort";
    }

    @Override
    public void doSort(int[] nums) {
        int n = nums.length;

        for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
            int key = nums[i];
            int j = i - 1;

            while (j >= 0 && nums[j] > key) {
                nums[j + 1] = nums[j];
                j--;
            }
            nums[j + 1] = key;

            SortingAlgorithm.setCurrentBar(j);
            SortingAlgorithm.sleepFor(delay);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void changeDelay(int delay) {
        this.delay = delay;
    }
}
```

MergeSort.java

```java
package sorting_algorithms;

import gui_components.GUIComponents;

public class MergeSort implements SortingAlgorithm {
    private int delay = GUIComponents.delaySlider.getValue() * 1000;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Merge Sort";
    }

    @Override
    public void doSort(int[] nums) {
        sort(nums, 0, nums.length - 1);
    }

    private void merge(int nums[], int l, int m, int r) {
        int n1 = m - l + 1;
        int n2 = r - m;

        int L[] = new int[n1];
        int R[] = new int[n2];

        for(int i = 0; i < n1; ++i)
            L[i] = nums[l + i];

        for(int j = 0; j < n2; ++j)
            R[j] = nums[m + 1 + j];

        int i = 0, j = 0;

        int k = l;
        while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
            if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
                nums[k] = L[i];
                i++;

                SortingAlgorithm.setCurrentBar(j);
                SortingAlgorithm.sleepFor(delay);

            } else {
                nums[k] = R[j];
                j++;

                SortingAlgorithm.setCurrentBar(j);
                SortingAlgorithm.sleepFor(delay);
            }
            k++;
        }

        while (i < n1) {
            nums[k] = L[i];
            i++;
            k++;

            SortingAlgorithm.setCurrentBar(j);
            SortingAlgorithm.sleepFor(delay);
        }

        while (j < n2) {
            nums[k] = R[j];
            j++;
            k++;

            SortingAlgorithm.setCurrentBar(j);
            SortingAlgorithm.sleepFor(delay);
        }
    }

    private void sort(int nums[], int l, int r) {
        if (l < r) {
            int m = (l + r) / 2;

            sort(nums, l, m);
            sort(nums, m + 1, r);

            merge(nums, l, m, r);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void changeDelay(int delay) {
        this.delay = delay;
    }
}
```

SortingAlgorithm.java

```java
package sorting_algorithms;

import drawing.PaintSurface;
import gui_components.GUIComponents;

/**
 * @author Daniel
 * 
 * Template for the sorting algorithms.
 */

public abstract interface SortingAlgorithm {
    public abstract String getName();

    public abstract void doSort(int[] nums);

    public abstract void changeDelay(int delay);

    public static void setCurrentBar(int currentBarIndex) {
        PaintSurface.currentBarIndex = currentBarIndex;
    }

    public static void sleepFor(int delay) {
        long timeElapsed;
        final long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        do {
            timeElapsed = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        } while(timeElapsed < delay);

        GUIComponents.displayPanel.repaint();
    }
}
```

Any helpful recommendations, comments, or suggestions are great. I'm only in high school, so any constructive criticism is nice! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE! Have a (another) look at [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and try and find a better title - I think *simulation* slightly off, as the sorting is as real as it comes, with *visualisation* welded in. It may prove useful to present more context: what details of `interface SortingAlgorithm` are your own design, what was specified beforehand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to CodeReview, your program is advanced for high school. I have some suggestions for you:

> ```
> private int delay = GUIComponents.delaySlider.getValue() * 1000;
> ```

You repetead this line all the classes implementing one different sorting method, you could use a constructor and pass this as a value like the class below:

```
public class BubbleSort implements SortingAlgorithm {

    private int delay;

    public BubbleSort(int delay) {
        this.delay = delay;
    }

    //other methods
}

//after in your code
int delay = GUIComponents.delaySlider.getValue() * 1000;
SortingAlgorithm bubble = new BubbleSort(delay);
```

I don't know if you are aware about the [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) class, that maps keys to value, you could use in the following way:

```
int delay = GUIComponents.delaySlider.getValue() * 1000;
Map<String, SortingAlgorithm> map = new TreeMap<String, SortingAlgorithm>();
map.put("Bubble sort", new BubbleSort(delay));
map.put("Quick sort", new QuickSort(delay));
Set<String> set = map.keySet(); //[Bubble sort, Quick sort]
SortingAlgorithm bubble = map.get("Bubble sort");
SortingAlgorithm quick = map.get("Quick sort");
```

In this example I created one `BubbleSort` object and one `QuickSort` object mapping them with their labels by `put` method and you can access them using the `get` method.

One thing you could change is the name of the class `NumbersList` : `List` is about a structure that can be modified while your class is an array, perhaps you could rename it as `NumbersArray`. Below my implementation for your class:

```
public class NumbersArray {
    private static int[] numbers;

    public static void generateArray(int amount) {
        numbers = new int[amount];

        double spacing = (double) Configs.APPLICATION_HEIGHT / amount;
        for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            numbers[i] = (int) ((i + 1) * spacing);
        }
    }

    public static void randomizeArray() {
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(numbers));
    }

    public static int[] getArray() {
        return numbers;
    }
}
```

I used `Collections.shuffle` method to randomize the elements of your array. Anyway again you made a great job.